# cluster markers on google maps, with MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, maps

I am using google maps and have it set up that my markers are stored in a table in my database and then by means of PHP and XML, they are plotted on the map.

However this does not take in to account for places in the same destination. I know there is a JavaScript way of creating clusters, but I was wondering if there was a way of doing by using MySQL and PHP like I have been doing.

Here is the tutorial where I was able to implement MySQL and PHP:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps?csw=1

Comment: Hey Rebecca, have you found a solution yet? I'm struggling with the same problem. Would be nice to hear from you :D